# Can I rewrite this as a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a bit of logic in my code and I'm wondering if there's a better way of re-writing it. I have two user-defined server objects (serverA and serverB) and I want to proceed if both of them are of enum `ServerType` `Web` or `Database`.

Current code is clumsy:

```
if((serverA.ServerType == ServerType.Web || serverA.ServerType == ServerType.Database) && (serverB.ServerType == ServerType.Web || serverB.ServerType == ServerType.Database))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

I'm after an elegant succinct way of writing that.

Comment: The logic of your `if` is different from what you say in your introduction. Is it "either" or "both"?

Comment: make a method and pass in serverA and B as arguments.  That would be cleaner, wouldn't it?

Comment: @brianpck thanks - clarified the question

Comment: I can't see how anonymous functions have anything to do with the question. Your `if` is fine and easy to understand (except you're using `=` instead of `==`, but I'm assuming it's a typo).

Comment: @Mephy but it looks so verbose, is there no terser way of expressing that?

Comment: @Mephy: I assume the problem is related to the repeating of identical code. With the given code you may have maintenance problems if somebody accidentally changes the first part half and not the second. If you extracted the logic to a single place (eg a lambda) then you'd have no problems with maintainability from that point of view. Of course I'd agree that anonymous functions shouldn't be used - no reason not to use proper named functions or properties. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have a new property in your user-defined server object

```
public class Server
{
    public ServerType ServerType { get; set; }

    public bool IsDatabaseOrWeb
    {
        get
        {
            return ServerType == ServerType.Web || ServerType == ServerType.Database;
        }            
    }
}
```

then your function would look like this

```
if (serverA.IsDatabaseOrWeb && serverB.IsDatabaseOrWeb)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

Comment: This is the most elegant solution IMO. Nice answer!

Comment: I answered this question before him with the same code....yet how did mine get placed way down below his answer?

Answer (score 2):

This way spells out more clearly that you are asking the same question about both servers and allows you to change the condition in one place if needed.

```
if(IsRightType(serverA) && IsRightType(serverB))
{
    // do stuff
}

bool IsRightType(Server server)
{
    return server.ServerType == ServerType.Web || server.ServerType == ServerType.Database;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe following solution would be more elegant. Implement an abstract class so all your server objects would inherit from it.

```
public enum ServerType
{
    Web,
    Database,
    SomethingElse
}

public class ServerA : ServerObject
{
}

public class ServerB : ServerObject
{
}

public abstract class ServerObject
{
    public ServerType ServerType { get; set; }
}
```

And then implement a method for checking if an object meets your condition.

```
public bool IfWebOrDatabase(ServerObject so)
{
    return so.ServerType == ServerType.Web || so.ServerType == ServerType.Database;
}
```

And use a much shorter version of the `If` then.

```
if (IfWebOrDatabase(serverA) && IfWebOrDatabase(serverB))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you need an abstract class. Presumably `serverA` and `serverB` are instances of the same class anyway...

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach is to use extension method for `enum ServerType`. A possible way to write the code would be the following:

```
public enum ServerType
{
    Web,
    Database,
    Bi
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsOperational(this ServerType st)
    {
        var operationalTypes  = new List<ServerType> { ServerType.Web, ServerType.Database };
        return operationalTypes.Contains(st);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var st1 = ServerType.Web;
        var st2 = ServerType.Database;
        var st3 = ServerType.Bi;

        bool isSt1Operational = st1.IsOperational();
        bool isSt2Operational = st2.IsOperational();
        bool isSt3Operational = st3.IsOperational();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to the class that contains ServerType:

```
public bool IsDatabaseOrWeb
{
   get
   {
      return (ServerType == ServerType.Web || ServerType == ServerType.Database);
   }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
if(ServerA.IsDatabaseOrWeb && ServerB.IsDatabaseOrWeb)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trend you should be noticing in these answers is that the solution is worse than the problem. If you wanted to use lambda expressions in linq, it gets even worse:

```
if (new Server[] { serverA, serverB }.All(s => new ServerType[] { ServerType.Web, ServerType.Database }.Contains(s.ServerType)))
{ 
}
```

Even if you break it apart:

```
var badIdea = new Server[] { entity, serverB };
var alsoBad = new ServerType[] { ServerType.Web, ServerType.Database };

if (badIdea.All(s => alsoBad.Contains(s.ServerType)))
{
}
```

Sometimes the simplest expression is still messy. Your if statement is fine unchanged. Maybe just put a carriage return in the middle so that you can see it on the screen all at once.

Comment: Please note that you could have introduced a lambda without having to introduce linq...

Comment: @Chris OK. Sure, but the point is that he's looking to simplify the conditional statement. To that end, linq and lambda are great bedfellows. But in this case, they still yield an inferior result.

Answer (score 0):

Bitflags may help here.

```
[Flags]
public enum ServerType
{
    None = 0,
    Web=1,
    Database = 2,
    Other = 4
}
```

To use it

```
var flags = ServerType.Web | ServerType.Database;
var bothWebOrDb = (serverA.ServerType & flags) 
    & (serverB.ServerType & flags);
if (bothWebOrDb != ServerType.None)
{                
}
```

Which be reduced to the following

```
var flags = ServerType.Web | ServerType.Database;
var bothWebOrDb = serverA.ServerType & serverB.ServerType & flags;
if (bothWebOrDb != ServerType.None)
{                
}
```